# Web Speech API Audio to Variable

Tags: javascript, audio, blob, webspeech-api

Is it possible to return the resulting audio from the Web Speech API (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API) to a variable that can be used via the Audio object?

I.E. something like the following (pseudo code):

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
var speechToAudioFileLink = speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
var audio = new Audio(speechToAudioFileLink);
audio.play();
```